# Misspelled 'setup()' method (wrong capitalization) @ line 21, column 5. @Before

Tags: grails

```
Misspelled 'setup()' method (wrong capitalization) @ line 21, column 5.
       @Before
```

```
public class GeographicControllerUnitTests extends Specification
{
    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
```

This is happening after upgrading to grails 3.3.3.  The test wasn't being recognized at all until I just added `extends Specification`.  What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to `extends GroovyTestCase` instead?

Comment: Could you please add some more details.

Comment: You wrote `setUp` and Gradle wants `setup` - pay attention to the lower case `U`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `setUp` and Gradle wants `setup` - pay attention to the lower case `U`